# Go Board Game - Recursive board group check

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion

Creating a Go Board Game but I'm stuck at checking the board for groups of stones that have been surrounded. To do this I thought I'd need to come up with some recursive functionality:

**(Updated)**

```
public List<Point> FindSurrounded(Board board, Point p, Player player, List<Point> group)
{
    int[,] b = board.board;
    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++){
        for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++)
        { 
            //check if group allready contain this spot
            if (p.X + dx < board.width && p.Y + dy < board.height && p.X + dx > 0 && p.Y + dy > 0 && (dy == 0 || dx == 0) && !(dy == 0 && dx == 0) && !group.Contains(new Point(p.X + dx, p.Y + dy))) 
            {
                // is the spot empty 
                if (b[p.X + dx, p.Y + dy] == 0)
                    return null;

                //check the suroundings of this spot and add them to the group
                //if(b[p.X + dx, p.Y + dy] != player.Identifier)// is there an enemy on this spot
                //    return new List<Point>();

                if (b[p.X + dx, p.Y + dy] != player.Identifier)
                {
                    group.Add(new Point(p.X + dx, p.Y + dy));
                    List<Point> temp = FindSurrounded(board, new Point(p.X + dx, p.Y + dy), player, new List<Point>());
                    if (temp == null)
                        return null;
                    //group.AddRange(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return group;
}
```

This code however gives me a **System.StackOverFlowException** error when I put a stone that surrounds stones of the opponent. The error would concern the following line:

```
            if (p.X + dx < board.width && p.Y + dy < board.height && p.X + dx > 0 && p.Y + dy > 0 && (dy == 0 || dx == 0) && !(dy == 0 && dx == 0) && !group.Contains(new Point(p.X + dx, p.Y + dy)))
```

But I have no idea why.

Does anyone know a way in which I can check whether a group of stones on the board is surrounded?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I still have to create an array to temporarily store all found stones that form a group together in order to remove them from the board when they're surrounded.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the specific question:

> Does anyone know a way in which I can check whether a group of stones on the board is surrounded?

Try this approach:

```
    Board b;

    int N, M; // dimensions
    int timer;
    int[,] mark; // assign each group of stones a different number

    int[,] mov = // constant to look around
    {
        { 0, -1 }, { 0, +1 },
        { -1, 0 }, { +1, 0 }
    };

    // Checks for a group of stones surrounded by enemy stones
    // Returns the first group found or null if there is no such group.
    public List<Point> CheckForSurrounded()
    {
        mark = new int[N,M];

        for (int i = 0; i < b.SizeX; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < b.SizeX; ++j)
                if (mark[i, j] == 0) // not visited
                {                        
                    var l = Fill(i, j);
                    if (l != null)
                        return l;
                }

        return null;
    }

    // Marks all neighboring stones of the same player in cell [x,y]
    // Returns the list of stones if they are surrounded
    private List<Point> Fill(int x, int y)
    {
        int head = 0;
        int tail = 0;
        var L = new List<Point>();

        mark[x, y] = ++timer;
        L.Add(new Point(x,y));

        while (head < tail)
        {
            x = L[head].X;
            y = L[head].Y;
            ++head;

            for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
            {
                // new coords
                int xx = x + mov[k,0];
                int yy = y + mov[k,1];

                if (xx >= 0 && xx < N && yy >= 0 && yy < M) // inside board
                {
                    if (mark[xx, yy] == 0) // not visited
                    {
                        if (b[xx, yy].IsEmpty) // if empty square => not surrounded
                            return null;
                        if (b[xx, yy].IsMine)
                        {
                            L.Add(new Point(xx,yy)); // add to queue
                            mark[xx, yy] = timer; // visited
                            ++tail;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // the group is surrouneded
        return L;
    }
```

This method doesn't use recursion so you don't have to deal with stack overflow (the exception not the site).

Comment: Doen't this throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` if `k = 4`at `int xx = x + mov[k,0];`? Because `mov` is just an int[4,2] array.

Comment: @Mike You are right. I was looking into 8 directions. Later I changed to look orthogonally adjacent squares and I forgot to update the loop. Updated in answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with code that does something like this.

pseudocode

```
    isSurrounded(stone){
          //mark that you have seen the stone before
          stone.seen = true;
          //check if all the surrounding spots are surrounded
          for(spot in surrounded.getSpotsAround){
              //An empty spot means the stone is not surrounded
              if(spot = empty){
                 return false;
              }
              else{
                 //don't recheck stones you have seen before or opponents stones
                 if(spot.stone.seen != true || !stone.belongsToOpponent){
                     //recursively call this method, if it returns false your stone is not surrounded
                     if(!isSurrounded(spot.stone){
                        return false;
                     }
                 }
              }
          }
          //if all of the surrounding stones are surrounded,seen already, or belong to other players, this stone is surrounded
          return true;
}
```

Then you would have to remove all the stones where seen = true or reset seen on all stones.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this

**(Updated)**

```
public List<Point> FindSurrounded(int[,] b, Point p, Player player, List<Point> group)
{
    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++){
        for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++)
        { 
            //check if group allready contain this spot
            if ((dy == 0 || dx == 0) && !(dy == 0 && dx == 0) && !group.Contains(new Point(p.X + dx, p.Y + dy)) 
            {
                // is the spot empty 
                if( b[p.X + dx, p.Y + dy] == 0) 
                    return null;

                if(b[p.X + dx, p.Y + dy] == player.Identifier)// is this your own stone
                {
                    //If this is my stone add it to the list and check for it
                    group.Add( new Point( p.X + dx, p.Y + dy ) );
                    List<Point> temp = removeSurrounded(b, new Point(p.X + dx, p.Y + dy), player, group);
                    if(temp == null)
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return group;
}
```

This returns null if there is any empty spot near your group else it will return a list of Points which represents your group.

Afterwards you can remove them like that

```
List<Point> group = FindSurrounded(b, p, player, new List<Point>());
if(group != null)
    foreach(Point point in group)
        b[point.x, point.y] = 0;
```

Comment: A nested loop over -1 to +1 seems very inefficient, iterating over 9 squares when you only need to check 4 (5?)!

Comment: You are right. I copied it from his code and just wanted to show the relevant part. But i removed the 9th stone like you mentioned. And i have no realy faster and easy understandable idea at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to think of a solution. I tried it but it doesn't seem to work though. I was wondering too how it would add points to the list as it just reterns new List<Point>() when it finds another stone of the opponent belonging to the group? Also I assumed RemoveSurrounded should be FindSurrounded? Thanks again!

Comment: You're right i forgot it. Sorry i couldn't test it. It have to be right before you call the next recursive step. I add it to my answer. I hope it works now. If not just write a comment and i write a test enviroment and debug it.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it now and changed a bit, but it's giving me a 'System.StackOverFlowException' when I put a stone that surrounds a group. I updated my post with the code I'm using right now, if you could check it for me it's much appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to add the Stone to the list. Compaire to my code. And also remove the `group.AddRange(temp)` if not you get the same point multiple times in the group.

Comment: Aah yes I see, I now removed the AddRange statement and added the stone to the list too. However it still gives me the System.StackOverflowException when I put a stone that surrounds a group of stones of the opponent

Comment: I chandeg a bit so it is more clear what i mean. Could you please post your new code?

Comment: Updated my code in the post, it's about the same as your code (but with some extra conditions for not going outside of the board) but still getting the error for when I try to surround a group of multiple stones (it does work when I try to surround only 1 stone though)

Comment: EDIT: Fixed! Thank you! Didn't see you changed the iterative function call to FindSurrounded to also pass the group as parameter instead of a new list (which made it an infinite loop), thank you very much for help! :)

Comment: @user2999349 Take a time to accept Mike's answer if it was helpful.